# Can any one convert this data as json serialization? I am getting this data from server bu unable to split it

Tags: json, swift

```
[
   {
      "complaint":{
         "createdAt":"2020-02-20",
         "updatedAt":"2020-02-20",
         "userId":420,
         "type":"Food",
         "subject":"No tasty",
         "description":"No tasty of food",
         "status":"OPEN",
         "date":null,
         "adminId":419,
         "id":433
      },
      "complaintComments":[
         {
            "id":23,
            "resolutionStatus":null,
            "resolutionDate":"2020-02-22T04:03:52.707+0000",
            "comments":"XCVCXZX",
            "complaintId":433,
            "updatedByUserId":420
         },
         {
            "id":30,
            "resolutionStatus":"RESOLVE",
            "resolutionDate":null,
            "comments":"Khdsth",
            "complaintId":433,
            "updatedByUserId":420
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "complaint":{
         "createdAt":"2020-02-20",
         "updatedAt":"2020-02-22",
         "userId":420,
         "type":"WI-FI",
         "subject":"G7YG7YG",
         "description":"8YTYGYG",
         "status":"OPEN",
         "date":null,
         "adminId":419,
         "id":423
      },
      "complaintComments":[
         {
            "id":16,
            "resolutionStatus":"RESOLVED",
            "resolutionDate":"2020-02-20T09:03:47.078+0000",
            "comments":"IUH8UHUUI",
            "complaintId":423,
            "updatedByUserId":420
         },
         {
            "id":26,
            "resolutionStatus":"REOPEN",
            "resolutionDate":"2020-02-22T09:42:23.791+0000",
            "comments":"8IOL;;KKLJJKHJKH",
            "complaintId":423,
            "updatedByUserId":420
         },
         {
            "id":29,
            "resolutionStatus":"Normal",
            "resolutionDate":null,
            "comments":"Pavankumar",
            "complaintId":423,
            "updatedByUserId":420
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "complaint":{
         "createdAt":"2020-02-22",
         "updatedAt":"2020-02-22",
         "userId":420,
         "type":"WI-FI",
         "subject":"vikas",
         "description":"vikas",
         "status":"OPEN",
         "date":null,
         "adminId":419,
         "id":611
      },
      "complaintComments":[
         {
            "id":31,
            "resolutionStatus":"REOPEN",
            "resolutionDate":null,
            "comments":"Mnbvcxz",
            "complaintId":611,
            "updatedByUserId":420
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, I think there should be one array of `complaints` and one array of `complaintComments` with different id to make things better.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Please add clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use Decodable, which is the defacto standard for parsing json in Swift. Then you should create structs for each item that you have.

```
struct Complaint: Decodable {
    let createdAt: String
    let updatedAt: String
    let userId: Int
    let type: String
    let subject: String
    let description: String
    let status: String
    let date: String?
    let adminId: Int
    let id: Int
}

struct ComplaintComments: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let resolutionStatus: String? // this is optional because you have shown that some of the values could be null.
    let resolutionDate: String? 
    let comments: String
    let complaintId: Int
    let updatedByUserId: Int
}

struct OrderComplaint: Decodable {
    var complaintComments: [ComplaintComments]
    var complaint: Complaint
}
```

Then you can use it in the following way:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let result = try! decoder.decode([OrderComplaint].self, from: data)
```

NB: You may not wish to force unwrap here as that will cause your app to crash, you should use a do/catch.

If an item in your struct could be null, then you need to make sure that item is an optional otherwise it will not parse correctly.

This [article](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/json-parsing-decoding/) by SwiftLee gives a good overview on how to use Decodable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this structure in your app

```
struct Complaints: Decodable {
    let complaints: Complaint
    let comments: [Comment]


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case complaints = "complaint"
        case comments = "complaintComments"
    }
}
struct Complaint: Decodable {
    let createdAt: String?
    let updatedAt: String?
    let userId: Int
    let type: String?
    let subject: String
}

struct  Comment: Decodable {
      let id: Int
      let resolutionStatus: String?
      let resolutionDate: String?
      let comments:String?
      let complaintId: Int
      let updatedByUserId: Int
}
```

then you can  decode like

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let result = try! decoder.decode([Complaints].self, from: data)
```